# Add SQLite to Android NDK project

Tags: android, c++, sqlite, android-ndk

I'm android developer, but new in android ndk, right now I'm trying to write an app using c++ via android ndk and all work with database should be done also with c++ code. I added sqlite to the project (I'm not sure if I do it correctly): I downloaded and saved these four files (shell.c, sqlite3.c, sqlite3.h, slite3ext.h) to src/main/cpp/sqlite folder. Here is my CMakeList.txt, where I add sqlite to the project:

```
add_library(native-lib

             SHARED

             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
             src/main/cpp/sqlite/sqlite3.c
             )
```

Did I do right? And how can I use it in code (connect to the db, create table, insert data, update data...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have these 3 files in your project: `sqlite3.c`, `sqlite3.h`, `sqlite3ext.h` (not sure about the last one). Basic operations (create db, create table and insert values):

```
bool createTable() {

    /* Open database */
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    rc = sqlite3_open(databaseName, &db);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        //Can't open database/
        sqlite3_open_v2(DB_FILE, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
    }

    /* Create SQL statement */
    const char *createQuery =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cities (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT);";

    /* Execute SQL statement */
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, createQuery, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        return false;
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return true;
}
```

insert:

```
bool insertToDb(CityWeather *pCityWeather) {
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;

    /* Open database */
    rc = sqlite3_open(databaseName, &db);
    if (rc) {
        sqlite3_open_v2(DB_FILE, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
    }

    const char *pCityName = pCityWeather->getName().c_str();
    char insertQuery[50];
    strcpy (insertQuery,"INSERT INTO cities (name) VALUES ('");
    strcat (insertQuery, pCityName);
    strcat (insertQuery, "');");
    puts (insertQuery);

    delete pCityWeather;

    /* Execute SQL statement */
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, insertQuery, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return true;
}
```